# Automatically or manually refreshing access token with flask_client on Google App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, authlib

I am successfully able to authorize my application with a 3rd party OAuth2 provider (Xero), but have been unable to refresh the token, either automatically, or manually.

The documentation suggests authlib can do this automatically. I have tried two different approaches from the Authlib documentation, on the [flask client docs](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html#auto-update-token-via-signal) they give an example of "Auto Update Token via Signal", and on the [web client docs](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#auto-update-token) they register an "update_token" function.

Using either approach, there is never an attempt made to refresh the token, the request is passed to Xero with the expired token, I receive an error, and the only way to continue is to manually re-authorize the application with Xero.

Here is the relevant code for the "update_token" method from the web client docs:

```
#this never ends up getting called.
def save_xero_token(name,token,refresh_token=None,access_token=None,tenant_id=None):
    logging.info('Called save xero token.')
    #removed irrelevant code that stores token in NDB here.

cache = Cache()
oauth = OAuth(app,cache=cache)
oauth.register(name='xero',
               client_id = Meta.xero_consumer_client_id,
               client_secret = Meta.xero_consumer_secret,
               access_token_url = 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
               authorize_url = 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
               fetch_token = fetch_xero_token,
               update_token = save_xero_token,
               client_kwargs={'scope':' '.join(Meta.xero_oauth_scopes)},
              )

xero_tenant_id = 'abcd-123-placeholder-for-stackoverflow'
url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/ABCD-123-PLACEHOLDER-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW'
headers = {'Xero-tenant-id':xero_tenant_id,'Accept':'application/json'}

response = oauth.xero.get(url,headers=headers)    #works fine until token is expired.
```

I am storing my token in the following NDB model:

```
class OAuth2Token(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    token_type = ndb.StringProperty()
    access_token = ndb.StringProperty()
    refresh_token = ndb.StringProperty()
    expires_at = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    xero_tenant_id = ndb.StringProperty()

    def to_token(self):
        return dict(
            access_token=self.access_token,
            token_type=self.token_type,
            refresh_token=self.refresh_token,
            expires_at=self.expires_at
        )
```

For completeness, here's how I store the initial response from Xero (which works fine):

```
@app.route('/XeroOAuthRedirect')
def xeroOAuthLanding():
    token = oauth.xero.authorize_access_token()
    connections_response = oauth.xero.get('https://api.xero.com/connections')
    connections = connections_response.json()
    for tenant in connections:
        print('saving first org, this app currently supports one xero org only.')
        save_xero_token('xero',token,tenant_id=tenant['tenantId'])

    return 'Authorized application with Xero'
```

How can I get automatic refreshing to work, and how can I manually trigger a refresh request when using the flask client, in the event automatic refreshing fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem here, and the root of it was the passing of a Cache (for temporary credential storage) when initializing OAuth:

```
cache = Cache()
oauth = OAuth(app,cache=cache)
```

When the cache is passed, it appears to preempt the update_token (and possibly fetch_token) parameters.

It should be simply:

```
oauth = OAuth(app)

oauth.register(name='xero',
               client_id = Meta.xero_consumer_client_id,
               client_secret = Meta.xero_consumer_secret,
               access_token_url = 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
               authorize_url = 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
               fetch_token = fetch_xero_token,
               update_token = save_xero_token,
               client_kwargs={'scope':' '.join(Meta.xero_oauth_scopes)},
              )
```

in addition, the parameters on my "save_xero_token" function needed to be adjusted to match the documentation, however this was not relevant to the original problem the question was addressing.